# What is Computer Science?

Tags: discussion, scope

This meta question is intended to be a place to direct people who ask what is Computer Science and answer misconceptions about it.

What is Computer Science?

Comment: I think this is subject to ongoing research.

Comment: If I wanted to know about XYZ and came to a site for XYZ, being directed to an answer in Meta would make me move on, and possibly leave the site forever. Stock answers for such can be found at Wikipedia; I would come to CS:SE because it has real people with real experience and diverse points of view. CS-definition and Misconception tags may work better. :)

Comment: Apart from my tongue-in-cheek response below, one can also consider the [ACM computer science curriculum](http://www.acm.org//education/curricula/ComputerScience2008.pdf) as a possible definition.

Comment: @Dave: so your definition of "computer science" is "what computer scientists study"? Would your definition of "computer scientist" then be "somebody who studies computer science"? I'm not sure this is that helpful. :-)

Comment: @PeterShor: Maybe not, but it helps pay the bills.

Answer (score 19):

It seems that our biggest problem is separating CS from related disciplines to some extent. I think this can be best achieved by analogy to fields people have more intuition for.

I have attempted to create such a table:

```
Software        Buildings         Generalprogrammer           construction worker     performs assigned tasks
software developer   foreman                 translates plans into work assignments
                                               and monitors workers
software engineer    architect               makes plans and develops principles
                                               then ensure some level of quality of
                                               the plans.
computer scientist   structural engineer,    develops and analyses methods/techniques
                     material scientist        for the above to use.
theoretical computer                         develops models and verifies principles
scientist            physicist                 that lead to and support new methods
                                               and techniques.
mathematician        mathematician           provides means to deal with models
                                               in a unified, abstract fashion.
                                               Develops meta models.
```

<sup>[[LaTeX source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/meta.cs_231.tex)]</sup>

Of course, such a table would have to be decorated with appropriated disclaimers: "This is no attempt at defining either notion rigorously; it is only a rough analogy to relate to general knowledge. The same person can perform more than one role. Some tasks may be associated with more than one role." and so on.

What do you think, can an analogy clarify what we have trouble defining clearly?

Do you have other/better analogies?

Answer (score 12):

[Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) is the *science* that studies *computation* and related issues. It has strong connections with other disciplines, particularly with: mathematics, computer and electronic engineering.

There are various lists of topics which are considered part of computer science:

- [ACM Computing Classification System](http://www.acm.org/about/class/ccs98-html)
- [ACM Special Interest Groups](http://www.acm.org/sigs)
- [arXiv Subject Areas](http://arxiv.org/corr/subjectclasses)

which among others include:

> discrete-mathematics, combinatorics, complexity-theory, algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry, formal-languages (and automata theory), logic, computability, information-theory, numerical-analysis, symbolic-computation, cryptography, security, 
>   artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, computer-vision, computational-linguistics, natural-language-processing, knowledge-representation-reasoning, robotics, 
>   computational-engineering (and science), computation-finance, 
>   databases, information-retrieval, 
>   distributed-computing, parallel-computing, neural-computing, evolutionary-computing,
>   algorithmic-game-theory, information-networks (and social-networks),
>   computer-graphics, multimedia, sound, 
>   computer-architecture (and hardware-architecture), computer-networks (and internet architecture), operating-systems,
>   programming-languages, software-engineering, human-computer-interaction

Comment: +1 for a good first answer. However, I feel like Raphael's point is a good one; we will never provide a useful, meaningful answer to the question of what computer science is (more broadly, what questions are on- and off-topic here) by listing specific areas... we need to seek some sort of more general criteria by which, e.g., "algorithms" and "robotics" can be judged to be on-topic, and "kittens", "Riemann sums", and "transformers" can be judged to be off-topic. Doing that is much harder, but I feel it would be much more useful...

Answer (score 11):

Misquoting [Justice Potter Stewart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it):

> I shall not today attempt further to define the kinds of material I understand to be embraced within that shorthand description *computer science*; and perhaps I could never succeed in intelligibly doing so. But *we* know it when *we* see it ... *so if in doubt, ask on meta*.

Answer (score 9):

Computer Science is the *science* of *computation*; that much seems clear. Less clear is how to define *science* and *computation* in a useful and meaningful way.

Generally, we might divide *science* according to two classifications: *formal* versus *empirical*, and *pure* versus *applied*. Whereas *formal science* (such as mathematics and much of computer science) relies on deductive reasoning from assumed truths, *empirical scienc* (such as physics and chemistry) relies on inductive reasoning from observed phenomena. Whereas the goal of *pure science* is to advance the state of scientific understanding, the goal of *applied science* is to use such understanding to harness the forces of Nature (in the broadest possible sense of the word) to achieve other goals.

We might define *computation* as a *transformation* applied to a piece of *information*. In the broadest possible sense, *computation* is, then, any process which causes a change to occur in the universe. There is no need to provide any more detailed definition than this.

*Computer Science*, then, consists of that part of the human endeavor which satisfies the following criteria:

- It is science, that is:

  - It is either (1) formal or (2) empirical:

    1. employs deductive reasoning from assumed truths
    2. employs inductive reasoning from observed phenomena
  - It is either (1) pure or (2) applied

    1. seeks to advance the state of scientific understanding
    2. seeks to apply scientific understanding to harness natural forces
- It studies computation, that is:

  - It studies either (1) transformations or (2) information

    1. processes which map information from one form to another
    2. entities subject to transformations

Topics which we might reasonably exclude from *Computer Science* include that part of the human endeavor which satisfies the following criteria:

- It is not a science, that is:

  - It contains elements which are neither (1) formal nor (2) empirical:

    1. does not employ deductive reasoning from assumed truths
    2. does not employ inductive reasoning from observed phenomena
  - It contains elements which are neither (1) pure or (2) applied:

    1. it does not seek to advance the state of scientific understanding
    2. it does not seek to apply scientific understanding to harness natural forces
- It does not study computation, that is:

  - It studies subjects which are neither (1) transformations nor (2) information

    1. processes which do not map information from one process to another, or for which properties of the mapping are not the focus of discussion
    2. entities not subject to transformations, or for which such properties influencing such transformations are not the focus of discussion

Comments, edits, and suggestions are welcome. I realize that it is practically impossible to give a universally accepted definition of either science or computation, and as such, I have tried to remain at a high level, possibly to a fault. Also, some of these items must be interpreted broadly (e.g., "scientific understanding" is intended to include *individual* understanding, so that it doesn't require research-level academic questions), while it might be preferable to interpret some of the items more narrowly (for instance, many elementary physics questions can be construed as computation, according to my definition; in a very precise sense, aren't they computation, after all?).

Comment: 1) "causes a change to occur in the universe" and "harness natural forces" are too general, imho, and dangerous; I don't think we want to deal with mysticism. 2) The second part is not useful; everybody should be able do negate the items in the first part.

Comment: @Raphael 1) In what sense does this language admit mysticism? How do you think these could be defined more narrowly, without throwing out the baby with the bathwater? 2) True, but natural language isn't as precise as mathematical language; I don't think it's out of line to explicitly state what I believe to be the negation of the first part. Of course, if your and my interpretations of the first part are the same, it would follow that the negations should be as well, hence the second part would be redundant.

Comment: @Raphael I think that part of the difficulty with trying to do what I'm doing is that to exclude programming from "computer science" is a more-or-less arbitrary decision... the more I think about it, the more true that seems. Is programming part of computer science? *Of course* it is, no matter how much I'd like to think it's not. It's clearly *applied formal science*, or at least that's the realization I keep coming back to.

Comment: @Patrick87, actually it is not as difficult as you think to state the programming per se is not computer science. For comparison, physics, civil engineering, and architecture are different from the job of people who actually build a building, paint its walls, etc. Computer science is the former, programming is the later. The confusion comes from the fact that almost all computer scientists also know how to write (at least simple) programs and many programmers know something about computer science. They are related but I think the distinction is still quite clear,

Comment: programming is a skill not a science. If you know how to program in C# it is like knowing how to control a crane. Software design and engineering can be part of computer science, but programming per se is not. I personally haven't seen anyone being called a computer scientist because they are a programmers. (Analogy between civil engineering and computer science and in particular software engineering is a standard one that can be found in many textbooks, and it is typically emphasized that software engineering and programming are diferent.)

Comment: @Kaveh I am aware of the standard arguments in favor of distinguishing "computer science" from "programming". And I would agree that, even according to the definitions in my post, not all "computer science" needs to involve programming, and not all "programming" needs to involve computer science. The point is that one *can* approach programming as an exercise in applied science, and as such, I propose the following: rather than making programming off-topic, we close "bad" programming questions either as not a real question, or too localized.

Comment: Give me the code := not a real question. Fix the code := too localized. But are questions like "why does this C++ code do X," "how could I do Y in functional language X," "does code snippet X perform better than code snippet Y," etc. really count as off-topic here? That seems excessive.

Comment: @Patrick87, yes, but the perspective is important here. If it is about coding or analyzing or debugging code in a particular language then it is probably off-topic and should be asked on SO. It might be possible to rephrase the question in a way that it becomes about algorithms or the programming language itself (not using it) or something else which are on-topic, but as long as it is not phrase that way it is off-topic IMHO, and should be on SO. Using a programming language and tools related to it is not computer science, and I think it is similar to using other softwares e.g. MS Office.

Comment: @Patrick87: Depends. Typically, such questions will be targeting language specifics, ergo offtopic. If it does not matter for the question wether the code is C++ or pseudo code, then it is fine.

Comment: @Kaveh I think where my doubt arises is when we try to say that what makes a programming question off-topic here is when it depends on the language used to express the program. This seems objectionable to me on the following grounds: we accept questions on algorithms design and analysis, the ends of "programming"; and we accept questions on languages, syntax and semantics, the means of "programming". But questions which involve both are not allowed? Are the on-topic questions on this site not closed under intersection? What if the person is unsure about where a problem lies?

Comment: @Raphael See my response to Kaveh above. I suppose another way of putting it is this: if asking about C++ language features from a programming-languages viewpoint is on-topic (and questions like this will certainly be targeting language specifics), then why should we exclude more *applied* questions, i.e., how does one do X in language Y? I suppose where my doubts regarding the anti-programming stance arise are this: genuine CS problems can arise during programming, and this community may be more able to help identify such situations. If we don't allow such questions, how will we know?

Comment: More generally, why have an anti-programming stance at all? Why not allow any questions, answer good programming questions with CS content here, migrate good programming questions without CS content to StackOverflow, and close bad programming questions like any others? We can add a line to the FAQ about StackOverflow being a potentially better site for specific problems with implementing programs in a particular language, or using a particular API or tool, etc.

Comment: It seems that asking people to check proofs (i.e., debug programs) is not off-topic on Mathematics; nor are questions which require (albeit implicitly) the use of a specific, formal syntax (i.e., programming language specifics). Why should CS treat programs differently than Mathematics treats proofs?

Comment: @Patrick87, First, the proposal was defined to exclude programming. These questions belong to SO. Second, no, as I explained above, they (programming per se) are off-topic because they are about using a software (in this case a programming language) which is not CS is about, similar cases: a question about using Linux is not a CS question in operating systems, a question about trouble shooting a router is not CS question in computer networks.

Comment: @Kaveh What I'm suggesting is that it might have been *wrong* to exclude programming; I'm aware of the original proposal. Indeed, until having thought about it a little more, I wholeheartedly agreed that excluding programming questions was a good idea. Now, I am not sure it is *right* to do so. Questions about software engineering *belong* on Programmers; questions about math *belong* on Mathematics; questions about scientific computing and computational science *belong* on Computational Science. These are not off topic; programming *belongs* on StackOverflow, but why treat it differently?

Comment: @Patrick87, because they are not computer science questions? (please reread my previous comment.)

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not sure you address the comparison to proofs on Mathematics. I can certainly write a Java program down on a piece of paper and reason about it, based on a formal (or semi-formal) specification, correct? It is a computational artifact; it could simulate a Turing machine. Should we close questions asking for a Turing machine? That's a syntax, a tool; valid answers might involve equivalent models of computation, such as recursive functions, cellular automata, two-stack PDAs, etc.

Comment: @Kaveh I see where you keep *stating* that programming is not computer science, and yet I cannot find where you are refuting any of my objections. Perhaps we could start a chat?

Comment: @Patrick87, TM is a theoretical model, no one is using it for programming. I really don't have time right now for a chat, maybe some other time. Anyways, I think the distinction is clear enough and although you trying to stretch what I wrote I think you get what I mean. As long as we are not going to allow arbitrary questions about computers (which are not CS), there is no reason to allow programming per se questions.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by objections, you have stated that some CS questions might belong to other SE sites and that is fine. A CS question is on-topic for cs.se, a non CS question is not. A programming per se question is not a CS question, therefore it is off-topic on cs.se. You want to discuss why questions about designing TMs are CS but programming question are not, and make some formal comparison between two. We can discuss it some other time, but the key here is the *perspective*, the goal of designing a TM is not really writing a program to do a task but understanding computability.

Comment: @Patrick87 (679): But this is exactly what we are about to do, aren't we? We can not prevent anyone from posting, after all. We can only close/migrate what we feel does not belong here. And if I look at SO, most of those question don't.

Comment: @Raphael A good point; my point is a bit different, though. If some programming questions are on-topic here, I feel we should have some sort of working criteria for distinguishing between on-topic and off-topic programming questions. Prohibiting *any* programming question is, IMHO, throwing out the baby with the bathwater; naturally, promoting the asking of *any* programming question is counterproductive. Then again, I wonder how bad it would be to allow programming questions? Are you afraid we'll get programming questions here that otherwise would have gone to StackOverflow?

Comment: StackOverflow is the more established site; more people will know about it, more people will be members there, at least for the foreseeable future. If we, from the beginning, make clear that the intent of this site is to ask questions with *scientific* content, as opposed to more general kinds of questions, and make sure the community is aware of StackOverflow and its purpose (as we are doing with Mathemtics, Programmers, etc.), I don't see why we should expect questions on programming to be any more of a problem than questions on software development or mathematics.

Comment: @Patrick87: It is a simple question of politics. If we say "No programming questions!" and allow exceptionally good ones to remain, everbody is happy. If we say "Everything is allowed!" and then close/migrate bad/offtopic ones, we have hell. As you say, we need a clear line; "no programming questions" is a clear line. We can always step over the line in either case, but this way does not hurt us.

Comment: @Raphael By a similar argument, you're less likely to be killed in an auto accident if you work from home, have your groceries delivered, and stay in your bedroom. Alright, that's a slippery slope, but I feel that we might run into the same problem here: by prohibiting programming questions, we may alienate a large segment of the potential user base; why risk asking a question here if you know it's OK on StackOverflow? Surely there are programming questions on StackOverflow which involve CS fundamentals and which could receive better treatment here?

Comment: In any event, I can tell that this suggestion isn't really going anywhere, and as such, I'm prepared to drop it. I just wanted to raise this concern, for the benefit of the community, as a possible consideration in setting up the FAQ and, more generally, in deciding what direction the site will take.

Comment: @Patrick87: I don't know how "good" (i.e. sciencey") SO can be. I *do* know that most questions with the computer-science tag are no good. I don't monitor the rest, so if you say there is meat to get, we should by any means try to. My impression has always been that SO was a lot like programmers' first level support.

Comment: @Patrick87 Across SE, people ask questions on the wrong site all the time. Sometimes because they've been banned on the right site for asking too many bad questions. SO is huge; posts that should have been on SO can represent a nontrivial amount on a smaller site. If we allowed programming questions, we would become IWasBannedFromSOButWantSomeoneToWriteMyCodeFromMe.SE. Furthermore, the whole point of having a separate site was that computer science questions didn't work on SO; we're not competing with SO, we're targeting a different topic.

Comment: @Patrick87: do you have an example of a programming question you think should be on topic on this site? I personally see programs as instantiations of algorithms; programming as an almost mechanical translation of the algorithm into something that works, and hence not something I'd categorize as 'science'. Programming language design is science about how to program well, but that does not make programming itself science. If we use TMs to specify something, we almost never do that to have the TM do work for us (like why we program), but rather to find out some science fact. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Furthermore, I think it's a bad idea to have overlap with SO: I already don't know where to go if I have a question that could either turn out to be a research level CS question or that could turn out to have an easy answer, and this could give rise to the same problem. Worse, if we allow programming questions, I don't see why we should allow *all* programming questions, at which point SO is a subset of our site. We have two websites to separate these two topics, as both fields are huge and deserve their own place for Q&A.

Comment: @Gilles I understand that we're targeting a different topic; what I fail to understand is why it's OK to allow overlap with sites like Programmers and Mathematics, but not OK to allow overlap with SO. The point about SO's being huge is well taken; indeed, if we want to prohibit programming questions for that reason alone, perhaps I can agree that it is a *necessary evil*. On an unrelated note, I take it that we are competing with Mathematics, Programming, and Computational Science? The up-voted FAQ suggestions allow questions that would be on-topic on those sites, as well.

Comment: @AlextenBrink Well, algorithms are expressed using a notation. Programming languages are simply one such notation. What is it about pseudocode that makes it preferable to C++? Is pseudocode to be disallowed? Your point about TMs' being OK because they aren't used "to do work for us" is unconvincing... does the appropriateness of a question depend on *the motives of the person asking it*? It seems to me that questions should be judged on their content... not the reasons for which they were asked. Maybe I have misunderstood.

Comment: To all: what makes programming in C++ *fundamentally* different from defining a formal grammar, an automaton, a piece of pseudocode? How is the rendering of an actual computer program distinct from the rendering of a formal proof of a mathematical statement? Even *that* can be done mechanically... indeed, what *is* the difference between that and programming?

Comment: @Patrick87 Join the chat! This comment thread is getting very long, and I'm interested in the topic.

Answer (score -2):

Do like GORDON cut a knot is his legendary manner: Computer Science is the science around the term Computer.

Answer (score -3):

there are some answer(s) here looking at more pragmatic angles on this topic eg how CS contrasts vs software engineering or programming & plays out post-graduation eg in the employment market. have worked in IT for many yrs and would suggest this is a complex question with quite a bit of nuance and no simple answers/distinctions even though it is a key question of interest to pre-university students attempting to make an informed decision about choice of major and future directions.

the analogy to building construction is somewhat useful. industry generally has two common roles: lead developer and developer. the latter is sometimes called a software engineer in more professional organizations, or simply a programmer. industry does sometimes have a "software architect" role who may or may not be involved in developing, their role is more to focus on "big picture" aspects of large systems [such as defining/streamlining inter-system interfaces, somewhat analogous to generating construction design "blueprints"], and this *dedicated* role is not so common except in large corporations; midsize-to-smaller corporations may have individuals that fill aspects of this role but are not fully dedicated to it (eg also do major development). [Grady Booch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grady_Booch) is an example of an expert figure who has great insight into more accurately/precisely delineating the software architect role.

furthermore at my university [which is presumably somewhat representative], software engineering is a branch of the engineering school and the student must take many engineering classes [which often have more depth in mathematics and physical science–eg physics, statics/dynamics, chemistry, thermodynamics, fluid mechanics!–than required of CS degrees] and specialize in software in their later grades. in other words the student is trained and certified as an engineer [there are certification societies] with a speciality in software.

post-university however these background distinctions may tend to blur in some corporations as it would be somewhat rare that both software engineers or computer scientists actually utilize all the diverse pedagogical/theoretical/scientific/engineering/mathematical aspects of their university education on particular jobs esp "entry level"–although over an entire *career* of course much more will come into play.

one approach to answering this question: *look up the course descriptions or curricula/requirements for CS vs software engineering majors at a school that offers both or across schools.*

there is quite a bit of material on the internet to add some insight (but *caveat* unfortunately/apparently not a lot of definitive/authoritative analysis on the subj). eg

- [difference between computer scientist and programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062811/difference-between-a-computer-scientist-and-computer-programmer) stackoverflow
- [can I become a software engr with a CS degree](http://www.bestcomputersciencedegrees.com/faq/can-i-become-a-software-engineer-with-a-computer-science-degree/)
- [computer science vs software engr](http://m.slashdot.org/story/177961) slashdot eg re Larson-Green vs Sinofsky dichotomy heading MS Windows
- [xkcd CS vs software engr discussion](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=11699)
- [difference between programmer and software engr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516/whats-the-difference-between-programmer-and-software-engineer) stackoverflow
- [differences between software engineer and computer programmer](http://work.chron.com/differences-between-software-engineer-computer-programmer-7587.html) stackoverflow

Comment: fyi other advanced math classes often reqd in engr school but not nec always CS: statistics, linear equations, differential equations, multidimensional calculus, etc

Comment: :( disappointed/ perplexed at low votes ... is it merely because it mentions & compares/ contrasts software engineering (incl programming/ development)? is it seen as too industry focused? in business, very many CS graduates work as programmers/ developers/ software engineers, the distinctions there are not so critical vs outside or abstractly, and quite possibly far more CS graduates are working in industry than academia.

Comment: some more contrast of cs vs software engr edu vs workplace in this controversial article/ blog ["more universities should shut down their CS programs"](http://blog.jeffreymcmanus.com/1924/more-universities-should-shut-down-their-computer-science-programs/) / McManus